# bWAPP: Connection failed: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'" when clicking install

Tags: linux, mysql, kali-linux

I've downloaded the most recent bWAPP from sourceforge.net and followed the `INSTALL.txt` guidelines to install it on a clean Kali Linux installation (2017.3).

I use the following MySQL connection settings:

```
// Database connection settings
$db_server = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "";
$db_name = "bWAPP";
```

However, pressing the "Click here to install bWAPP." on http://localhost/bWAPP/install.php results in the following error message: "Connection failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'".

[image]

I've searched Google and it seems that other people have similar issue, but no solution is documented anywhere.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is MariaDB database backend which comes installed with Kali Linux:

> MariaDB is a community-developed fork of the MySQL relational database
>   management system intended to remain free under the GNU GPL.

This database backend doesn't allow `root@localhost` user access from applications.

I fixed the issue by creating a new database user, `bwappu`, with granted priviledges for the `bwapp` database:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on bwapp.* to 'bwappu'@'localhost';
```

Also, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28068155/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-after-new-instal

Answer (score 4):

A little bit more detalization for correct answer by Nicolas Lykke Iversen:

Go to the terminal:

```
root@kali: mysql -u root -p
enter password 'toor'
MariaDB [(none)]> use mysql;
MariaDB[(mysql)]> create user 'username'@'localhost' identified by 'my_password';
MariaDB[(mysql)]> grant all privileges on bWAPP.* to 'username'@'localhost' identified by 'my_password';
```

Go to /var/www/html/bWAPP/admin/settings.php and set:

```
$db_username = "username";
$db_password = "my_password";
```

Then go to http://localhost/bWAPP/install.php and install it.

PS: **username** & **my_password** - you may use any words you like

Comment: When you say `$db_password = "password";`, do you mean literally `$db_password = "password";`, or do you mean ``$db_password = "ILoveSuperUser";``, where the second password *is replaced by the actual password you chose?*  In other words, what parts of your answer are literal and what parts are placeholders?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and figured out the solution for me at least. The $db_password field must be equal to the password for your SQL root user.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me on Kali Linux machine, but I am not sure if this is also applicable for ubuntu.
Thank you.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).